# How to create workspace like MS office applications?

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-office, mdi

I'm wanting to create something similar to this picture from excel:

[image: Excel with two documents]

I did something similar in winforms with MDI child windows. I understand from other questions that MDI is not supported in WPF. However, isn't excel 2010 a WPF application ?

So I started with a canvas and a user control. I'm easily able to create user controls and place on the canvas but.. they don't look like a window and they don't have the support of a window for moving, resizing, closing etc and I'm realising that's a lot of code I need to find and get working.

I've read that MS has dropped MDI for a reason but on the otherhand, it looks like office is implementing it ?

Before I use a project like http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/ I thought i'd ask and see if there is something "MS approved" I should be using.

Comment: MS has been heavily advicing against MDI for several user, because of usability issues. That is why WPF doesn't support it. And no, Excel is not a WPF application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AvalonDock](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/) from [Extended Wpf Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) may be helpful. Use it with Caliburn.Micro to manage windows. Example solution: https://github.com/tgjones/gemini

Answer (score 0):

MDI *is* supported by the framework, just like anything else (for example a docking layout, floating windows, ...), but as you figured out Microsoft itself doesn't supply a ready-to-use implementation. Just as it doesn't supply an implementation of docking layout/floating windows/.... So if you want to use it you either build it yourself or use something as in the link you posted.